# API(s) that let me mask a user's phone number more cheaply than Twilio?

Tags: voice, phone-number, twilio

I'm making an app and when the user clicks dial, instead of dialing the end user, they will dial an intermediary number which will then dial the end user.

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) does this, bu is too costly at $0.03/min.

Are there other APIs that offer a cheaper solution?

Comment: What about Google Voice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention 'when the user clicks dial', so it sounds like it's web-based... Twilio just released Twilio Client - perhaps you can use that to accomplish this at 1/4 cent per minute.

Twilio Client: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client

Twilio Pricing: https://www.twilio.com/pricing

Answer (score 0):

The only others I know of are [CallFire](http://callfire.com) @ $0.035 / min, and [Tropo](http://tropo.com) @ $0.003 /min. So, nothing cheaper than I'm aware of, no.